# Renaming table name in SQLServer

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database say test in SQLServer 2008 which have almost more than 100 tables inside it .
I have requirement that I have to add prefix to these tables .

for e.g. table `employee` should be renamed as `companyName_employee` . `companyName_` is the prefix I want to apply.So table `department` should be renamed to `companyName_department`

Currently I can rename tables one by one by running below query :

```
sp_rename employee, companyName_employee
```

`sp_rename` only renames one table at a time.

I am new to SQLServer so please suggest if there is a way to rename multiple tables in one query

Comment: Do you need to preserve the data? What performance requirements are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the sp_rename statements using dynamic sql. Like this:

```
SELECT 'exec sp_rename ''' + name + ''', ''companyName_' + name + ''''
FROM sysObjects
WHERE type = 'U'
```

Comment: and how to run this dynamic SQL ... because When I run this query it is giving result as `exec sp_rename 'qualityrating', ' companyName_qualityrating'` but It does actually renames the tables . how to run this statement ?

Comment: Copy all the statements, then execute them by hand. This query only generates the queries, it will not execute them.

Comment: @Shree It is possible to generate the update statements and execute them at once - but this would require cursors and is a lot more involved. Probably not worth it for a once off table rename like this. As Pred said - with this answer you can generate the statements, copy and run them manually.